# Do these remarks in a generated rails scaffold do anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

When I generate a scaffold in rails, I noticed that the methods are prefaced with # remarks. I haven't been able to find any documentation as to if they actually do anything of if they are similar to what looks like remarks in application.js that look like remarks but are really code.

For example:

```
  # POST /attachments
  # POST /attachments.json
  def create
```

and

```
  # GET /attachments/1
  # GET /attachments/1.json
  def show
  end
```

I am using rubymine as my editor.

Comment: Those are just comments in Ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't do any magic behind the scenes. They are just comments to help you out.

By default, scaffolding will direct POST requests to `create()`, and GET of a particular resource (e.g. `/resources/<id>`) to `show()`. These associations are defined in your routes, and scaffolding applies this convention. You're free to change them in your routes if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just [comments](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#comment) in Ruby. They are ignored by the Ruby interpreter and are meant for the developer.